# Springsteen collectors - What are the "must have" ROIOs?

Tags: bruce-springsteen

I know some might consider this "too broad" or a "list question", but there are probably a very limited number of answers here.

I'm looking to explore Bruce Springsteen's illustrious touring career.  I'm wondering what are the dates/titles of some of the "must have" ROIOs out there.  Either spectacular performance, rare setlist, alternate lyrics or some other feature that makes you feel it would be a great primer for a new collector.  Preferably from a SB/FM source, though better audience recordings are OK.

(For the uninitiated, "ROIO" stands for Recording Of Indeterminate Origin and is sort of the "politically correct" way of saying "bootleg")

Answer (score 2):

My 5 favorites are:

- Pièce de Résistance
- Winterland
- Where the River ends
- Nassau Night
- Coliseum Night

Comment: Hi, could you expand your answer with more details?

Comment: If possible, could you list dates/sources, and add a little about why you like these particular shows?  Thanks!